# Angular2 Application with ng store in IE 11 is leaking memory

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-11, ngrx

We are developing a Angular2 SPA with Ngrx store.

We have properly unsubscribed the Observable and following the correct Change Detection Strategy (`OnPush`) as per the requirement.

The application will be accessed by users in IE11 browser on Windows7. 
When the application started initially the IE process memory is less than 200 MB. But whenever we refresh the page it is increasing by 30 MB and finally crashes when IE process memory reach 1 GB.

The application contains charts (Chartjs) which is customized for requirement.
Any suggestions to identify and fix memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Try to nail down *what exactly* causes leak in the first place:

- Is this happening for blank/dummy ng2 app with single controller and no logic?
- Is this happening with chartjs enabled?
- Is this happening with ngrx enabled?
- Is this happening with both ngrx and chartjs enabled?